# Regex - How to delete the first 10 lines / and the last 10 lines

Tags: regex, text, notepad

I'm trying to make a regex that deletes the first and the last 10 lines of my 200 txt files with "Search and Replace all"

I tried `(\s*^(\h*\S.*)){10}` to delete the first 10 lines blanks included but it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Notepad++, you will need to match the whole document text but only capure lines from 11 to the end.

*Find*: `\A.*(?:\R.*){9}\R?([\s\S]*)`
*Replace*: `$1`

To remove the last 10 lines:

*Find*: `^.*(?:\R.*){9}\z`
*Replace*: empty

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of the document
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break symbols (the whole first line)
- `(?:\R.*){9}` - 9 sequences of a line break (`\R`) followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `\R?`  - an optional line break (if there are just 10 lines)
- `([\s\S]*)` - Group 1 capturing the rest of the document.

The second regex:

- `^`  - start of a line
- `.*`  - the line itself up to the line break
- `(?:\R.*){9}` - 9 lines: line break + any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `\z`  - *the end of the document*.

`$1` is the backreference to the text stored in Group 1.

The result of hitting a  *Replace All* button on a 20+ line document to remove the first 10 lines:

[image]

And the last 10 lines:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple Replace All using this

`(?m)(?:\A(?>^.*\R?){10}|(?>^.*\R?){10}\z)`

Expanded

```
 (?m)
 (?:
      \A
      (?> ^ .* \R? ){10}
   |  (?> ^ .* \R? ){10}
      \z
 )
```

If it doesn't support the `\R` syntax, substitute

`(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85)` - Ascii
`(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85|\x{2028}|\x{2029})` - Unicode